# Refactor React Radio buttons and Dynamic Input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, radio-group

I have 3 radio buttons that need to dynamically show and remove an input field when the radio button is true for that group

I am looking for another set of eyes to help me refactor this code. I feel like there is better way to clean this up or utilize better logic to remain DRY without bugging up the state or turning this into an uncontrolled component. The code works and the repo is  here https://github.com/GregPetropoulos/Naval-Letter-Generator

```js
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

const Radios = () => {
  const [viaIsChecked, setViaIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [refIsChecked, setRefIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [encIsChecked, setEncIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const [addViaInput, setAddViaInput] = useState([]);
  const [addRefInput, setAddRefInput] = useState([]);
  const [addEncInput, setAddEncInput] = useState([]);

  // If the VIA radio button is checked Yes, show the first input field and add button
  // If an additional VIA field is added show the remove button
  // * HANDLING THE RADIO CLICK AND SETTING THE INTIAL STATE
  const viaOnChange = () => {
    setViaIsChecked(!viaIsChecked);
    setAddViaInput([{ via: '' }]);
  };
  const refOnChange = () => {
    setRefIsChecked(!refIsChecked);
    setAddRefInput([{ references: '' }]);
  };

  const encOnChange = () => {
    setEncIsChecked(!encIsChecked);
    setAddEncInput([{ enclosures: '' }]);
  };

  // * HANDLING THE ADDITION OF HTML INPUT ELEMENTS
  const addViaInputTag = () => {
    setAddViaInput((prev) => [...prev, { via: '' }]);
  };
  const addRefInputTag = () => {
    setAddRefInput((prev) => [...prev, { references: '' }]);
  };
  const addEncInputTag = () => {
    setAddEncInput((prev) => [...prev, { enclosures: '' }]);
  };

  // * HANDLING THE REMOVAL OF HTML INPUT ELEMENTS
  // Two ways to remove an item either by clicking remove button or click the button radio "No"
  const removeViaInputTag = (e, index) => {
    const inputs = [...addViaInput];
    const arrItemRemoved = inputs.filter((item, idx) => idx !== index);
    setAddViaInput(arrItemRemoved);
  };

  const removeRefInputTag = (e, index) => {
    const inputs = [...addRefInput];
    const arrItemRemoved = inputs.filter((item, idx) => idx !== index);
    setAddRefInput(arrItemRemoved);
  };
  const removeEncInputTag = (e, index) => {
    const inputs = [...addEncInput];
    const arrItemRemoved = inputs.filter((item, idx) => idx !== index);
    setAddEncInput(arrItemRemoved);
  };

  // * HADLING THE ONCHANGES FOR TEXT INPUTS SEPERATELY
  const handleViaTextInput = (e, index) => {
    const textViaInputs = [...addViaInput];
    // destructure
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    // access the index and name ex: at 0 index the value of via is ''
    // due to destrcuture we have access to name, value
    textViaInputs[index][name] = value;
    setAddViaInput(textViaInputs);
  };

  const handleRefTextInput = (e, index) => {
    const textRefInputs = [...addRefInput];
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    textRefInputs[index][name] = value;
    setAddRefInput(textRefInputs);
  };

  const handleEncTextInput = (e, index) => {
    const textEncInputs = [...addEncInput];
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    textEncInputs[index][name] = value;
    setAddEncInput(textEncInputs);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <label className='sm:text-xl mt-7'> Optional Items</label>
      
      {/****--------------1st RADIO BUTTON AND FIELDS-----------------****/}
      <div className='form-control block items-center text-xs my-1 sm:text-lg'>

        <label className='mb-2 mr-2'> Do you have a VIA?</label>
        <input
          type='radio'
          name='radio-1'
          id='radio-1'
          value='1'
          checked={viaIsChecked === true}
          onChange={viaOnChange}
          className='radio radio-primary mx-2 radio-xs checked:bg-blue-500 sm:radio-lg sm:m-0'
        />{' '}
        Yes
        <input
          type='radio'
          name='radio-1'
          id='radio-1'
          value='1'
          checked={viaIsChecked === false}
          onChange={viaOnChange}
          className='radio  mx-2 radio-xs radio-primary checked:bg-red-500 sm:radio-lg'
        />
        No
      </div>
      {viaIsChecked
        ? addViaInput.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                name='via'
                id='via'
                value={item.via}
                onChange={(e) => handleViaTextInput(e, index)}
                type='text'
                className='block w-full text-black text-[8px] my-3 rounded-md py-2 pl-1 pr-2 shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-base sm:pl-9 sm:pr-3'
                placeholder='Enter The Via (Title, name of activity (Code), location when needed'
              />

              {/* Add button appears on last input field added */}
              {addViaInput.length - 1 === index && addViaInput.length < 3 && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn mr-4 btn-sm sm:btn'
                  onClick={addViaInputTag}>
                  Add VIA
                </button>
              )}

              {addViaInput.length > 1 && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn btn-sm sm:btn'
                  onClick={(e) => removeViaInputTag(e, index)}>
                  Remove VIA
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}

      {/****--------------2nd RADIO BUTTON AND FIELDS-----------------****/}
      <div className='form-control block items-center text-xs my-1 sm:text-lg'>
        <label className='mb-2 mr-2'> Do you have References</label>
        <input
          type='radio'
          name='radio-2'
          id='radio-2'
          value='2'
          checked={refIsChecked === true}
          onChange={refOnChange}
          className='radio radio-primary mx-2 radio-xs checked:bg-blue-500 sm:radio-lg sm:m-0'
        />{' '}
        Yes
        <input
          type='radio'
          name='radio-2'
          id='radio-2'
          value='2'
          checked={refIsChecked === false}
          onChange={refOnChange}
          className='radio  mx-2 radio-xs radio-primary checked:bg-red-500 sm:radio-lg'
        />
        No
      </div>
      {refIsChecked
        ? addRefInput.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                name='references'
                id='references'
                value={item.references}
                onChange={(e) => handleRefTextInput(e, index)}
                type='text'
                className='block w-full text-black text-[8px] my-3 rounded-md py-2 pl-1 pr-2 shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-base sm:pl-9 sm:pr-3'
                placeholder='Enter The Via (Title, name of activity (Code), location when needed'
              />

              {/* Add button appears on last input field added */}
              {addRefInput.length - 1 === index && addRefInput.length < 3 && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn mr-4 btn-sm sm:btn'
                  onClick={addRefInputTag}>
                  Add Ref
                </button>
              )}

              {addRefInput.length > 1 && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn btn-sm sm:btn'
                  onClick={(e) => removeRefInputTag(e, index)}>
                  Remove Ref
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
      {/****--------------3nd RADIO BUTTON AND FIELDS-----------------****/}
      <div className='form-control block items-center text-xs my-1 sm:text-lg'>
        <label className='mb-2 mr-2'> Do you have Enclosures</label>
        <input
          type='radio'
          name='radio-3'
          id='radio-3'
          value='3'
          checked={encIsChecked === true}
          onChange={encOnChange}
          className='radio radio-primary mx-2 radio-xs checked:bg-blue-500 sm:radio-lg sm:m-0'
        />{' '}
        Yes
        <input
          type='radio'
          name='radio-3'
          id='radio-3'
          value='3'
          checked={encIsChecked === false}
          onChange={encOnChange}
          className='radio  mx-2 radio-xs radio-primary checked:bg-red-500 sm:radio-lg'
        />
        No
      </div>
      {encIsChecked
        ? addEncInput.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                name='enclosures'
                id='enclosures'
                value={item.enclosures}
                onChange={(e) => handleEncTextInput(e, index)}
                type='text'
                className='block w-full text-black text-[8px] my-3 rounded-md py-2 pl-1 pr-2 shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-base sm:pl-9 sm:pr-3'
                placeholder='Enter The Via (Title, name of activity (Code), location when needed'
              />

              {/* Add button appears on last input field added */}
              {addEncInput.length - 1 === index && addEncInput.length < 3 && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn mr-4 btn-sm sm:btn'
                  onClick={addEncInputTag}>
                  Add Encl
                </button>
              )}

              {addEncInput.length > 1 && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn btn-sm sm:btn'
                  onClick={(e) => removeEncInputTag(e, index)}>
                  Remove Encl
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Radios;
```

[Radio Buttons UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22GKG.png)

Comment: Its pretty subjective but I would create one component for  showing input with buttons and one component for radio buttons and then wrap them up in third component and use that component all the places where they are required in your code it looks like you need it for 3 places. Each component will take care of its own state.

Comment: @Mahesh Thank you for responding...Those were my initial thoughts. Where I am conflicted is the DRY worth the children and passing around the state?

Comment: FYI, You can request a code review here => https://codereview.stackexchange.com/